# create database with no cpanel access

Tags: php, mysql, linux, hosting, shared

I have an installation script, it works fine on localhost but on a share hosting I always get "access denied", below is the installation script mysql code. its really weird how it only works locally on localhost.

```
if(isset($_POST['install'])) {
$AdminUsername = HtmlSpecialChars(strip_tags($_POST['admin_username']));
$AdminPassword = HtmlSpecialChars(strip_tags($_POST['admin_password']));
$dbhost = strip_tags($_POST['dbhost']);
$dbuser = strip_tags($_POST['dbuser']);
$dbpass = $_POST['dbpass'];
$sitename = strip_tags($_POST['sitename']);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE tickets
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(32),
Email VARCHAR(40),
Subject VARCHAR(40),
Message TEXT(500),
open VARCHAR(10),
TimeCreated VARCHAR(40),
TimeUpdated VARCHAR(40),
hash VARCHAR(100)
)";
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE config 
(
AdminUsername VARCHAR(32),
AdminPassword VARCHAR(32)
)";
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO config (AdminUsername,AdminPassword) VALUES ('$AdminUsername','$AdminPassword')";
 if(empty($dbhost)) {
echo "<div style='color:red;'>MySQL Database Host should not be empty!</div><br /><br />";
} elseif(empty($dbuser)) {
echo "<div style='color:red;'>MySQL Database User should not be empty!</div><br /><br />";
} elseif(empty($dbpass)) {
echo "<div style='color:red;'>MySQL Database Password should not be empty!</div><br /><br />"; 
} elseif(empty($sitename)) {
echo "<div style='color:red;'>Please enter a name for your new installation (It can be whatever you want)</div><br /><br />";
} elseif(empty($AdminUsername)) {
echo "<div style='color:red;'>Admin Username should not be empty!</div><br /><br />";
} elseif (empty($AdminPassword)) {
echo "<div style='color:red;'>Admin Password should not be empty!</div><br /><br />";
}
else {
$file = fopen('../configuration/config.php','r+');
fwrite($file, '<?php $dbhost = "'. $dbhost.'"; $dbuser = "'. $dbuser.'"; $dbpass = "'. $dbpass.'";  $sitename = "'. $sitename.'"; $temp = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);');
include('../configuration/config.php');
$temp->query("CREATE DATABASE tests");
$file2 = fopen('../configuration/config.php','r+');
fwrite($file2, '<?php $dbhost = "'. $dbhost.'"; $dbuser = "'. $dbuser.'"; $dbpass = "'. $dbpass.'";  $sitename = "'. $sitename.'"; $dbname = "tests"; $con = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);');
include('../configuration/config.php');
fopen('install.lock','w');
header('Location: ../index.php');
}
}
}
} else {
echo "installation is locked";
}
```

How can I make it so it works on shared hostings? please , I would really appreciate! thanks in advance 
I couldnt find a answer on stackoverflow so I decided to post it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permissions to do that.

You can't create databases if the user doesn't have the permissions to do so. You either have to set those permission for the specific user. I doubt a shared host will let you if they prevented this in the first place.

Comment: thats not a very helpful answer, i know that I dont have permission, thats why im asking how to solve the problem

Comment: Not sure what you want to solve. Make sure you get the permissions for the user.

Comment: how can I solve the permission problem then? I've seen alot of installation scripts that work on shared hosting

Comment: Your localhost 'root'  has all permissions possible. On shared this would be dangers and a security breach.

Comment: i guess I can just remove the database creating query and force the user to do it manually

Comment: Other installation scripts won't work either if they don't have the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually weird that it won't let you from a shared hosting environment but it will from localhost. That's how mysql permissions work, they are defined by the user and the ip from which the user is making the request. Your installation script would work on localhost because 'user'@'localhost' has Create and insert permissions, however it looks like it is the case that 'user'@'sharedhostingip' does not have these permissions and thus you're request is met with an access denied response. If your user has permissions to modify users then try granting create and insert permissions to your user @ the ip address of your server, otherwise you will have to contact your DBA to get those permissions added.

Hope this helps.